# Urban Airship deep link on remote notification launch - IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, react-native, urbanairship.com

I am using react-native to run my ios application, and I currently have push notifications successfully working through urban airship. I also have deep linking working, but only in several different situations:

Application is launched from another application(notes) by clicking on a url link using the specified url template("my_template://my_url"), and the application successfully opens and calls the deep link.

Application is already open in the background and the application is opened using the push notification sent from urban airship with a deep link action. This opens the application from the background and performs the deep link

I need the application to launch when clicking on the push notification from urban airship as well as perform the deep link, but right now it will only launch the application and the deep link will only perform if the application is already in the background.

Here is my code in AppDelegate.m that is performing urban airship notifications(only displaying relevant code):

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "RCTRootView.h"
#import "RCTLinkingManager.h"
#import <AirshipKit/AirshipKit.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [UAirship takeOff];
    [UAirship push].userPushNotificationsEnabled = YES;

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
}
```

In the above code, the openURL argument is only called in the two situations listed above.

Messed around with handling different urban airship situations, but couldn't get them to work. [UASituation documentation](http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/ios.html#actions)

Answer (score 0):

When is the action not working for you?

The deep link action has a default predicate that rejects the `UASituationForegroundPush`situation. Thats to prevent the application from automatically deep linking if a push is received in the foreground. You can remote the predicate with the following:

```
[[UAirship shared].actionRegistry updatePredicate:nil
                                 forEntryWithName:kUADeepLinkActionDefaultRegistryName];
```

Comment: The action is not working when the application is closed.  So when the push notification launches the app, it is not deep linking, but if the app is already open in the background(not the foreground), the deep link will work.  Again it doesn't accept notifications with the app in the foreground, which is perfectly fine with me, it just won't deep link when the app is launched from the push notification.

Comment: Hey ralepinski, just solved the issue, turns out it wasn't an issue with urban airship, I ran a breakpoint on the openURL function and the url was passing correctly, it was just an issue with the RCTLinkingManager(I'll have to solve that issue separately).  Thanks for the help anyways, I'm brand new to stackoverflow, so I'll bump up your answer once I hit the required reputation level.

Comment: @PhilipBrown Glad you figured it out :).